# How to install recursively my directories and files in BitBake recipe

Tags: shell, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I would like to install/copy all my directories and files recursively from working directory to my target package rootfs on yocto build system.
I tried the solution provided by Tobias Bystricky in

[How to install directory structure recursively in OpenEmbedded BitBake recipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817222/how-to-install-directory-structure-recursively-in-openembedded-bitbake-recipe/39979123#39979123)

but I faced "No such file or directory" error

I did ,

```
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/xxx/
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/xxx/yyy
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/xxx/yyy/zzz
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/xxx/yyy/zzz/kkk
find ${WORKDIR}/xxx/yyy/zzz/kkk/ -type f -exec 'install -m 0755 "{}" ${D}${sysconfdir}/xxx/yyy/zzz/kkk/' \;
```

Error message is ,

> find: `install -m 0755 / "Path to working
>   dir" /xxx/yyy/zzz/kkk/test_file.txt / "Path to all
>   packages" / "MyPackage" /image/etc/xxx/yyy/zzz/kkk/': No such file or
>   directory

I checked & confirmed that exact working directory path & Package directory paths are present. please let me know if i am missing any.

please suggest if any other way.

Answer (score 10):

```
cp -r
```

is known to leak user information. In the OE repos, the canonical form is

```
cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v SOURCE DESTINATION
```

see also [corresponding OE patch](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/116525/)

Answer (score 3):

i also tried as below , did not work.

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/xxx/yyy/zzz/kkk/* ${D}${sysconfdir}/xxx/yyy/zzz/kkk
```

and 
just tried simple cp -r  in do_install(), it  works

```
cp -r ${WORKDIR}/xxx/yyy/zzz ${D}${sysconfdir}/xxx/yyy
```