# How do I write a yocto/bitbake recipe to copy a directory to the target root file system

Tags: directory, copy, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I have a directory of  'binary' (i.e. not to be compiled) files and just want them to be installed onto my target root file system.

I have looked at several articles, none of which seem to work for me.

The desired functionality of this recipe is:

myRecipe/myFiles/ --> myRootFs/dir/to/install

My current attempt is:

```
SRC_URI += "file://myDir"

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}/path/to/dir/on/fs
         install -m ${WORKDIR}/myDir ${D}/path/to/dir/on/fs
}
```

I can't complain about the Yocto documentation overall, it's really good! Just can't find an example of something like this!

Comment: For a good example of this see psplash_git.bb -> do_install_append

Comment: Modify this line "install -m ${WORKDIR}/myDir ${D}/path/to/dir/on/fs" to  "install -m ${WORKDIR}/myDir/* ${D}/path/to/dir/on/fs"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install recursively my directories and files in BitBake recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980145/how-to-install-recursively-my-directories-and-files-in-bitbake-recipe)

Answer (score 20):

You just have to copy these files into your target rootfs. Do not forget to pakage them if they are not installed in standard locations.

```
SRC_URI += "file://myDir"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/path/to/dir/on/fs
    cp -r ${WORKDIR}/myDir ${D}/path/to/dir/on/fs
}
FILES_${PN} += "/path/to/dir/on/fs"
```

Comment: This seems to copy the directory, but none of the files or other directories within it. I'm assuming I have to state all of these explicitly then. Is there a sensible, quick way to do this?

Comment: Of course it does. It's why I used `cp -r` for recursive copy.

Comment: I used cp -r, it copies the 'myDir' directory to the FS but none of its contents...

Comment: Ok.  Try `cp -r ${WORKDIR}/myDir/* ${D}/path/to/dir/on/fs`. It is strange. I'll have a look. Are you sure `myDir` is not empty ?

Answer (score 6):

Take care that with a simple recursive copy, you will end up having **host contamination warnings** so you would need to copy with the following parameters:

```
do_install() {
     [...]
     cp --preserve=mode,timestamps -R ${S}${anydir}/Data/* ${D}${anyotherdir}/Data
     [...]
}
```

As other recipes in poky do, or just follow the official [recommendations](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/tasks.html?highlight=do_install#do-install) to avoid problems with ownership and permissions.

Comment: What are the differences between using `cp` and `install -m` as other users suggested?

Comment: I just added a direct link to documentation. My advice is to use always install, except when you need some recursive copying.

Comment: This is pretty much the only correct answer, the thread itself being a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980145/how-to-install-recursively-my-directories-and-files-in-bitbake-recipe/47084404#47084404)

Answer (score 3):

For a recipe folder like this:

```
.
├── files
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── b.c
│   └── Makefile
└── myrecipe.bb
```

You can use the following recipe to install it on a specific folder into your rootfs:

```
SRC_URI = " file://*"
do_install() {
    install -d ${WORKDIR}/my/dir/on/rootfs
    install -m 0755 ${S}/* ${WORKDIR}/my/dir/on/rootfs/*
}
FILES_${PN} = "/my/dir/on/rootfs/* "
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it did not work for you becuase you forgot to add mode value, after "install -m",

see man page of install command:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/install

```
install -m [mode] src destination
```